# How to test a variable setted in an async function?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to test the value of a variable after the execution of an async function, but when I try to read it it is an empty array (the variable should have an array with objects), I also put some console.log() inside the function an it is working right.

This is my first time using Jasmine and Karma so any help will be fine.

The function inside my component

```
async refresh() {
let requestUserProfile;
let data
// this._fuseSplashScreenService.hide();

// this.showLoading('Cargando documentos...');

//requestUserProfile = this.getUserProfile();
this._restService.getDocumentsLimit(100, 1, undefined).subscribe((documents: any) => {
    //Here is just a part of this function
    this.moreData = documents.data;
});
```

}

The variable moreData is the one who I've been trying to test.

The test code;

```
describe('DashboardComponent', () => {
  let component: DashboardComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<DashboardComponent>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HomeModule, HttpClientModule, RouterTestingModule, NoopAnimationsModule, MatDialogModule ],
      declarations: [ DashboardComponent ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(DashboardComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  //This is the one 
  it('should have info', async () =>{
      await component.refresh();
      console.log(component.moreData);
      //expect(component.moreData).not.toBe(null)
  })
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not with the async function or something. In your test scripts, what you need to do is, mock the service, and return some value and then it will automatically cover that variable.

Here is what you need to do:

```
////////////////// Use Injectable and create a mock-service;

@Injectable()
class MockService extends RestService {
  ////////////////////// Mock your method here
  getDocumentsLimit() {
    return of({ 
        data: {
             // You know what response comes here, so use that here;
             someData: 'someDataValue'
        }
    }
  }
}

describe('DashboardComponent', () => {
  let component: DashboardComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<DashboardComponent>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HomeModule, HttpClientModule, RouterTestingModule, NoopAnimationsModule, MatDialogModule ],
      declarations: [ DashboardComponent ],
      ///////////////// ADD THIS LINE IN THE PROVIDERS /////////////
      providers: [
          {
            provide: RestService,
            useClass: MockService
          }
      ] 
    })
    .compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(DashboardComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  //This is the one 
  ////////////////////// YOUR TEST CASE WILL BECOME THIS
  it('should have info', () =>{
      spyOn(component, 'refresh').and.callThrough();
      component.refresh();
      expect(component.refresh).toHaveBeenCalled();
  })
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This resolved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

_restService.getDocumentsLimit(...) probably returns an asynchronous observable (http call I assume), meaning that refresh() returns immediately and subscription's callback method is expected to be invoked sometimes in the future (when results arrive from http call). However, test execution is terminated before callback gets a chance to be invoked, so assignment to this.moreData never happens.

Such scenarios where you loose control over you tests are not desired. The solution is to get rid of dependencies that may interfere with you test, or better say make them controllable by [mocking](https://angular.io/guide/testing-services#angular-testbed).

In your test you should therefore mock the getDocumentsLimit(...) method, but the key here is to have it return a synchronous observable with fake data, then expect this.moreData to hold that fake data.